# How to plot different graphs according to user input? R shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to build a web app in shiny that would allow for different user input and then plot graphs/output data tables accordingly.  I am using WHO's data about suicide rates and I want to make a few plots possible:
1.  Histogram, y=suicide_no, x=age group, gender neutral (female and male combined) sample=world or one of the countries (if one country is selected create a subset of data) . So far I renderred this separately because there is no need to specify the country when I want the global data, otherwise I would've used input$country as the fill
2.  Histogram y=suicide_no, x=age group, gender specific (female and male separately, two bars for each age group), sample=world or one of the countries. I renderred this separately to gender neutral as for gender specific I include fill=gender.
3.  Line graph y=suicide_no, x=years, gender neutral, sample=world or one/several countries
4.  Line graph y=suicide_no, x=years, gender specific, sample=world or one country only (two lines which represent male and female)

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
setwd("C:\\Users\\Lenovoi7\\Shrewsbury School\\IT\\Coursework")
who<-data.frame(read.csv("who.csv",  stringsAsFactors = TRUE))
countries <- sort(unique(who$country))
countries<-union(countries, c("World"))

ui<-fluidPage(

   sidebarLayout(

     sidebarPanel(

#Allow user to choose the variable which should be plotted on the x axis
selectInput(
  "x", "Please choose the x variable",
  c("",
    "Year" = "year",
    "Age group" = "age")),

#only show this panel when the x variable is chosen
conditionalPanel(
  condition = "input.x == 'age' || input.x == 'year'",
  selectInput( 
    inputId = "gender",
    label = "Please specify the gender characteristics", 
    choices = c("", "Gender neutral" = "gender_neutral",
                "Gender specific" = "gender_specific"),
    selected = NULL),

  #only show this panel if the input is gender_specific
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.gender == 'gender_specific'",
      selectInput(
      inputId = "country",
      label = "Select a country:", 
      choices = countries,
      selected = "Bosnia and Herzegovina")),

  conditionalPanel(
   condition = "input.gender == 'gender_neutral'",
    selectInput(
      inputId = "country",
      label = "Select a country:", 
      choices = countries,
      selected = "Bosnia and Herzegovina")))),

mainPanel(
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = 'input.x=="age" & input.gender=="gender_neutral" & input.country=="world"',
    plotOutput("hgnw")),

  conditionalPanel(
    #any one country
    condition = 'input.x=="year" & input.gender=="gender_neutral"& input.country==input$country',

    plotOutput("lgnw")
  ))))

server <- function(input, output) {

#render the plot when x=age, gender=gender_neutral, sample=world
 output$hgnw<-renderPlot({
 validate(need(input$x=="age" & input$gender=="gender_neutral"))
 ggplot(data=who, aes(x=age)) + geom_bar(aes(weights=suicides_no))

  })

#render the plot when x=year, gender=gender_neutral, sample=world
 output$lgnw <- renderPlot({
 validate(need(input$x=="year", message=FALSE))

 ggplot(data=who, aes(x=year)) + geom_line(aes(y=suicides_no)) + geom_point(aes(y=suicides_no))
   })

  }
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have created a few (not all) conditional panels and plot outputs and then tried to test whether the plot calculated in the server works when called in the main panel (different plot is rendered depending on the user input which I tried to accomplish with validate function) but it does not. I am wondering  how do I approach this problem in the server and main panel. Do I use if statements or conditional panels? This does not currently work and it may not even  be a good approach for my problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would try doing this with a single `plotOutput` and no `conditionalPanel`s.  Inside `renderPlot` for your one `plotOutput`, you can use a series of if statements to determine what the user selected and therefore what `ggplot` commands you need to issue.

Comment: I tried to do it like this:
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  x<-reactive({input$x})
  
  gender<-reactive({input$gender})
  
  country<-reactive({input$country})
  
  output$graph <- renderPlot(

    if (x()=="age"){
      
      if (gender()=="gender_neutral"){
        
        if (country()=="world"){
          
          ggplot(data=who, aes(x=year)) + geom_bar(aes(weights=suicides_no), position="dodge")
        }
      }
    }
  )
}

But it still does not output anything when I choose age group, gender neutral and world?

Comment: Could it be that the list of options coming from the `countries` vector contains `World` (capitalized) but the condition in the server looks for `world` (lowercase)?  I can't run the full code without access to `who.csv`; that's the only thing I can see at the moment.

Comment: Yes, that works great! Thank you.